# MAMP shows php errors but no warnings

Tags: php, error-handling, warnings, error-reporting

I use both WAMP and MAMP.  I have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` in both environments.  However, if I run the following simple script:

```
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

On WAMP, I receive a warning message that says `$x` has not been initialized.  On MAMP, I get a blank screen with no warning.

I find these warnings helpful.  Does anyone know how I can turn on these warnings on in MAMP?

Again, in MAMP, I have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` (6143), and `display_errors` set to `On`.

**Update**: To be clear, I do see fatal error messages on both WAMP and MAMP.  However, I only see warning messages on WAMP.  I would like to see warnings on MAMP as well.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1);` on top

Comment: Did you restart MAMP after changing these settings?

Comment: Shankar, I tried adding `error_reporting(-1)` to no avail.

Comment: Anigel, yes, I did restart MAMP, and php is still displaying no warnings.

Comment: What does phpinfo show? If it does not show display_errors on then check that you have edited the correct php.ini file which is shown in phpinfo

Comment: Anigel, I ran phpinfo(), and `display_errors` is set to `On`.  However, I'm still not receiving warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ten days of searching, I finally found the answer.  Apparently the issue was not WAMP- or MAMP-specific at all.

I am running my scripts within CodeIgniter, and a function called set_error_handler() was suppressing all warnings, even though error_reporting and display_errors were set to show all errors and warnings.

Hopefully this helps someone out there and saves them ten days of bewilderment.